# Assign script to gpio interrupt in Yocto

Tags: interrupt, gpio

I am using iMX53qsb with Yocto and want to run some script by button pressing. Now I have enabled interrupt on user button (as gpio), but I can't imagine how to  handle it.

Could anyone point me how to handle this interrupt or where I can read more about this?

Button is Volume_up (GPIO_2_14), set as gpio and interrupt event is falling edge; in 
cat /proc/interrupts I see following:

```
174:  0  -  gpiolib
```

and second column is counting on every pressing.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: ty, @JimHawkins , I have read this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was long and hard path.. and now it works.
Finally, GPIO is handled by sysfs, not kernel module (the reason is that user-space scripts cannot be called from kernel-space).

In my case step sequence looks like follow:

1. Editing hardware description file to enable button pin as GPIO (arch/arm/mach-mx5/mx53_loco.c, by default it is defined as button);
2. Setting GPIO through sysfs (export desire GPIO pin, set direction, set edge);
3. Writing program that polls desire GPIO by `poll()`;
4. Making poll-program starts at system startup in background.